# Connecting hive to flutter

Tags: flutter, hive

While trying to connect hive to flutter, i get the following error:

> pub get failed command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart
> __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example" pub env: {   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",   "PUB_ENVIRONMENT":
> "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",   "PUB_CACHE":
> "C:\Users\abhin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache", } exit code: 65
>
> exit code 65

Can anybody help me with a solution?

Comment: Please provide more information about your code, the details about the problem and steps you have follow...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

```
Delete your pubspec.lock
```

run following commands

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run --verbose
```